# How to verify the button pressed in a previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I apologize for my English ..

I am new to android development and am working with Fragments.
The doubt is as follows:
My first fragment has 2 buttons, button A and button B. Both lead for a second fragment with a list of items to be selected. Up to this point all right.
What I wonder is after selecting any item in the list must go to the third fragment then how to check if the A button was pressed to take the Fragment A or B button was pressed to take the Fragment B?

Comment: You are saying that, if I press A, when I click on an item in the list, it should take me to a third fragment A. And, if I press B, it should take me to a fragment B after I press an item in the list. Is this it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be calling the second fragment on Button click.

Do this inside `onClick()` method

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("selectedButton", "A"); // or B if button B is clicked
SecondFragment fragobj = new SecondFragment();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragobj).commit();
```

and to receive in second fragment's `onCreateView()` method like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String selectedButton = getArguments().getString("selectedButton"); // would give you A or B as passed
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Hello Rohit5k2, thank you for your answer was exactly what I needed. I had read something setPressed but to no avail, the way you did is perfect. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `Fragment` you can pass it parameters.

For example:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int someInt) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

After that, in the `onCreateView()` you can receive them

```
getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
```

When you create the second fragment pass it a parameters that indicates if the "launcher" was button A or B